# using variable in xpath on ruby with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, open-uri

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

1.upto(10) do |x|
url = TOPSECRET
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

title = page.xpath('//span[@class="tit"][#{x}]').inner_html

puts "#{x}, #{title}"
end
```

the error occurs [#{x}] <= here

how can I fix this?

Comment: When you're using string interpolation you'll have to use quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: What is "the error"? It'd difficult to help when we don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your use of single quotes instead of double quotes.

change this:

```
title = page.xpath('//span[@class="tit"][#{x}]').inner_html
```

to this:

```
title = page.xpath("//span[@class=\"tit\"][#{x}]").inner_html
```

for proper variable expansion.  Note also the escaping of internal double quotes.

Comment: Thanks but why did u put the double \ ?

Comment: In a double quoted string, internal double quotes need to be escaped or they will be read as a terminator.  

    `irb> string = "testing" => "testing"`  

    `irb> string = "\"testing\""  => ""testing"" `

Comment: Glad to help.  Please accept the answer when you get a chance.  Let me know if you hit any other snags with Mechanize/Nokogiri and I'll take a look.

Comment: hey @david I posted [a new question about cron job with google api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433380/authorization-issue-with-cron-crawler-inserting-data-into-google-spreadsheet-usi) please help me if you could. Thanks!