# Authorization issue with cron crawler inserting data into Google spreadsheet using Google API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cron, google-api, web-crawler, google-api-client

My project is to crawl the certain web data and put them into my Google spreadsheet every morning 9:00. And it has to get the authorization to read & write something. That's why the code below is located at the top.

```
# Google API
CLIENT_ID = blah blah
CLIENT_SECRET = blah blah
OAUTH_SCOPE = blah blah
REDIRECT_URI = blah blah

# Authorization_code
def get_authorization_code 
    client = Google::APIClient.new
    client.authorization.client_id = CLIENT_ID
    client.authorization.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
    client.authorization.scope = OAUTH_SCOPE
    client.authorization.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

    uri = client.authorization.authorization_uri
    Launchy.open(uri)

    # Exchange authorization code for access token
    $stdout.write  "Enter authorization code: "
    client.authorization.code = gets.chomp
    client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
    client.authorization
end

authorization_code = get_authorization_code
access_token  = authorization_code.access_token
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)
```

But with this in the code, even though I set up the cron job, I probably have to wake up in the morning and `Enter authorization code` to get it done. But I don't want to.

Please tell me how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to [Ruby google_drive gem oAuth2 saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789804/ruby-google-drive-gem-oauth2-saving)

I needed to get a refresh token and make my code use it like below.

```
CLIENT_ID = '!!!'
CLIENT_SECRET = '!!!'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
REFRESH_TOKEN = '!!!'

client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.client_id = CLIENT_ID
client.authorization.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
client.authorization.scope = OAUTH_SCOPE
client.authorization.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
client.authorization.refresh_token = REFRESH_TOKEN
client.authorization.refresh! 

access_token = client.authorization.access_token
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)
```